# how do I check the last time dbreindex or an index defrag was executed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a quick tsql I can use to check when was the last time a dbreindex, index defrag and update stats was executed on the database?

Appreciate everyone's quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the queries below and see if that is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_system_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'YourDb')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('YourTable')


select name as index_name,
         stats_date( object_id, index_id) as stats_update_date
from  sys.indexes
where object_id = object_id('YourTable');


Select * 

From sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```